# How to change .preserve argument in dplyr's slice

Tags: r, dplyr, tidy

According the `dplyr` documentation on the `slice` function [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/slice.html), it takes an boolean argument `.preserve` which I take to mean when TRUE, will keep the original indices when subsetting rows. However the code

```
library(dplyr)
library(ISLR)
set.seed(1)
train <- sample(nrow(OJ), 800)

OJ.train <- OJ %>%
        dplyr::select(-c(WeekofPurchase, StoreID, STORE)) %>%
        slice(train, .preserve=TRUE)

head(OJ.train)
```

produces the following error

```
Error in slice_impl(.data, dots) : slice only accepts one expression
Calls: %>% ... <Anonymous> -> slice -> slice.data.frame -> slice_impl
Execution halted
```

As does using `preserve=TRUE` and simply `TRUE` as final argument. Am I missing something here? How do I change this argument from its default (FALSE)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem stems from looking at the documentation of `slice` online instead of checking out your installed package's version of `slice`.

The option `.preserve` has only been introduced in version 0.8.0 of `dplyr`: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/96b0395a74adf4f405e9293334bafc968653cc96/NEWS.md. The documentation you mention (online) is for this version.

You probably have a previous version installed on your computer which does not have yet the option `.preserve`, hence the error.

Comment: Thanks, I feel stupid for not checking. I just updated so I assumed I had the latest, but I guess I should pull from github instead of using CRAN if I want the latest.